# Unity - Background visible between tiles edges at certain points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I'm making a platformer in Unity and can't seem to find a way around this. The scene view looks perfectly fine but while playing the game, the background is visible as lines at certain points between the tile edges. A screenshot of the same is attached.
[The image shows the overlapping background as a line on the left of the player.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUfST.png)

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the tile border is hard up against the edge of a sprite.  To avoid it, your sprite map tiles need to repeat their edges for a pixel or two beyond the tile border.  It's a bit hard to explain in text.

Here's an okay video on the issue and how to fix it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QW53YIjhQsA

*I'll update this answer when I get a chance so that it's not relying on an outside source which could one day disappear.*

Comment: Hey @HumanWrites, I editted my tilemap in the manner that the guy in the video did, but I'm still getting the same results. I also tried bordering all the tiles that I'm using with a separate coloured tile, but to no avail. Hopefully you can help me.